# ubuntu 13.10 run chrome with oracle(sun) jdk1.7 32 bit and not 64 bit

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, 64-bit, java

I have (manually downloaded and extracted) both jdk 1.7 32 and 64 bit in two folders.

I want chrome to run applets with jdk1.7 32 bit unfortunately it keeps asking me to install java plugin when i access a test page such as:

```
http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp?detect=jre
```

the way I point to jdk 1.7 32 bit is as following:

/opt/google/chrome/plugins/libnpjp2.so -> /home/myuser/dev/jdk1.7.0-32/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so

note when i run this java it looks fine:

```
e$ /home/myuser/dev/jdk1.7.0-32/bin/java -version java version "1.7.0_25" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15) Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

if i run chrome with 64 bit java plugin it runs applets well (does not need to install java plugin)

see:

```
/opt/google/chrome/plugins/libnpjp2.so -> /home/myuser/dev/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so
```

can anyone guide me through having chrome run well with jre 1.7 32 bit plugin?

thanks!